# Restored Sections of the Talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara, censorship

Koren Publishers restored sections of the Talmud that had been removed due to censorship. Have any other publishers of Shas done the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Oz Vehadar, while often reliant on manuscripts/other editions of the Talmud, want to maintain the pagination of the original Vilna Shas. As such, they bring all the censored passages, but as a side note in their "Hagahos VeTizyunim".

The new Moznaim gemarros inserted the deleted passages within the text. For example, compare an original Vilna Shas [Sanhedrin 43a](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14302&st=&pgnum=86), and the [new Moznaim version](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37969&st=&pgnum=96) with deleted passages added (see Mesoras HaShas note 10).

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Is pagination the only reason why those publishers don't include those sections in the main body of text?

Comment: I would assume most publishers don't want to tamper with the original Vilna Shas. Some add it on the side, and some insert it into the text.

Comment: I know I saw one edition that put it in as the main text, but in a different font or slightly smaller size, to let you know that it's been restored after censorship. Anyone recall who did it that way?